# Removing AM/PM in Android Time picker Widget

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Is there any way to remove the `AM/PM` in a `Time Picker Widget`?

[image]

I have this function in my application but its purpose is to select only Hour and Minutes not including AM/PM, I tried to `setIs24HourView(true)` but it makes the time 24hours, I only want 12 hours.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the only way `TimePicker` will hide that on its own is if it's in 24-hour mode. See if [this code](http://pastebin.com/LJSN75L7) works for ya, before I post it. I can't test it, at the moment.

Comment: @MikeM. -> and it's works! Thank you! Please make it Answer instead of comment, Also this can help the others so if you put the code in Answer instead of link that will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is no public method in `TimePicker` to directly hide or show the AM/PM chooser. However, a look at the source code will give us the name of the resource ID for that `View`, which we can get with the system `Resources`. Then it's simply a matter of finding the `View`, and setting its visibility to `GONE`.

```
private void hideAmPmLayout(TimePicker picker) {
    final int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("ampm_layout", "id", "android");
    final View amPmLayout = picker.findViewById(id);
    if(amPmLayout != null) {
        amPmLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do the same for `TimePickerDialog`?

Comment: @ShinilMS You can call `findViewById()` on a `Dialog`.

Comment: Yea right, but the view is always null. I can't hide the AM/PM in `TimePickerDialog`.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I was calling `hideAmPmLayout(mTimePickerDialog);` before `mTimePickerDialog.show();`.

Comment: I got this error
**Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : View!> findViewById(p0: Int): T!
Please specify it explicitly.**

Comment: @PAGosai That's nothing specific to this code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45267041, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44950401.