# Not able to "findViewById" in Kotlin. Getting error "Type inference failed"

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, type-inference

I am getting the following error when I try to find a `RecycleView` by id.

> **Error:-** 
>   Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter **T**

[image: Error]

Code:

```
class FirstRecycleViewExample : AppCompatActivity() {
    val data = arrayListOf<String>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.first_recycleview)

        val recycler_view =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView ///IN THIS LINE I AM GETTING THE ERROR

        data.add("First Data")
        data.add("Second Data")
        data.add("Third Data")
        data.add("Forth Data")
        data.add("Fifth Data")

        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CustomRecycleAdapter(data)

        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try something like:

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
```

You can use `Kotlin Android Extensions` too for that. Check the doc [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).
With it, you can call `recycler_view` directly in your code.

**Kotlin Android Extensions:**

- In your app `gradle.build` add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`
- In your class add import for `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*` where `<layout>` is the filename of your layout.
- That's it, you can call `recycler_view` directly in your code.

How does it work? The first time that you call `recycler_view`, a call to `findViewById` is done and *cached*.

Comment: In latest version I'm getting warning to remove the Type from <>. As Android studio forcing me to use only diamond operator `<>` when I use it then it is giving error.

Answer (score 51):

You're on API level 26, where the return type of `findViewById` is now a generic `T` instead of `View` and can therefore be inferred. You can see the relevant changelog [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/26/changes.html).

So you should be able to do this:

```
val recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
```

Or this:

```
val recycler_view: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
```

Answer (score 21):

**DEPRECATED**

In `Kotlin` we can get the id of the view without the use of the  `findViewById` syntax.

For example we are using the following the layout from that we will get the id of the view and perform operation

> **Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

We are able to find the id of the view by using the following code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
    welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!" ////WE ARE GETTING THE IDS WITHOUT USING THE FINDVIEWBYID syntax
}
```

> **HOW?**

To be able to use it, you need an special import (the one I write below), but the IDE is able to auto-import it. Couldn’t be easier!

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME.*/// HERE "YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME" IS YOUR LAYOUT NAME WHICH U HAVE INFLATED IN onCreate()/onCreateView()
```

We need to import this property to get the id of the view without the use of the `findviewbyid` syntax.

For more information on this topic than please refer this link :- [Click here](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

**UPDATE**

Now the kotlin-android-extensions is deprecated , instead of using the kotlin provided binding , we can use now the **View-Binding** and it works same as above solution, Just you need to use the below in your app gradle

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Usually Kotlin can infer your type using the info provided in the brackets.

In this case, it can't so you would have to specify it explicitly like this

```
findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
```

Not really sure about the type though but that is how you should specify it

I'd like to add that, using [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko), you can further simplify your code like this:

```
val recycler_view : RecyclerView =  find(R.id.recycler_view)
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this line for your code as Whatever you are using controller.

```
val tvHello = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvHello)
```

Answer (score 7):

Was unable to access the ui components like OP faced looks like below was needed inside app gradle:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Even though after adding this line android studio was still not able to auto resolve the imports for kotlin synthetics so you may need to invalidate cache and restart.

If still not working then import manually depending on views

- activity /fragment view:  import
  kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<your_activity_view>.*
- normal views :
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<your_layout_view>.view.*

Update - 2

If you are getting this info warning -

> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated.

plugin 'kotlin-android-extensions' is going to be deprecated.
So add below in your app gradle

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore giving ids to variables in kotlin. You just need to use a plugin

Paste this in your gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and then you don't need to assign ids to var, you can just do it like

```
 recycler_view.setAdapter(youradapter);
```

Comment: I got gradle error by this error when apply kotlin 1.8.0, can not run project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Here `bind` generic function use to bind view. its general function it's can use for any view.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recycler_view : RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        recycler_view = bind(R.id.recycler_view)
    }
}

fun <T : View> Activity.bind(@IdRes res : Int) : T {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")    
    return findViewById(res) as T
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to create an object to do things with a view.
You can just use the id. For example,
**Kotlin**

```
recycle_view.adapter = adapter
```

is same as,
**Java**

```
RecycleView recycle_view = (RecycleView) findViewById(recycle_view);
recycle_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```