# Kotlin Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but TextView was expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Good day!
Using `Kotlin` 1.1.51 in `Android Studio 3.0`, targeting `Android API 26` to create `RecyclerView` with next `ViewHolder`, but receiving error on building the project:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but TextView was expected

So I can't find `TextView` directly to `ViewHolder` variable, but found around way - find View and after that cast with `as TextView` as you can see in the code for `holder.`textView. Doesn't look so good, so are there solutions how to  prevent this error or is it a bug?
The code of `RecyclerView`.Adapter:

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_item_view, parent, false)
        return VH(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        val event: TimelineEvent = items[position]

        // does not work because of error in VH class
        holder.timeView.text = event.time

        // works
        (holder.textView as TextView).text = event.text
    }

    class VH(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        // error: Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but TextView was expected
        val timeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_time)

        // works fine
        val textView: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_text)
    }
```

Comment: With the newer (than `1.1.51`) and in recent `1.2.71` recent  Kotlin version the error has disappeared

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're not on API level 26 or newer yet. That's when `findViewById` was changed so that it returns a generic `T` instead of the base `View` class, which enables you to use it from Kotlin in [these ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950543/4465208).

You can either manually cast the result of the `findViewById` call as @AlexTa suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218952/4465208), or you can update your support library version to `26` or later - the latest currently is `27.0.0`. These new versions are available from [Google's Maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven).

Comment: Sorry, I'm on API 26, will update my question with this info

Comment: You might be targeting 26, but if you're extending `AppCompatActivity`, then it's the support library version that has to be at least the first stable release of 26.

Comment: You know that supportlib version cannot be less than compileSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion cannot be less than targetSdkVersion?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to cast found view as expected type, to do so:

```
val timeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_time) as TextView
```

or

```
val timeView: TextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timeline_item_time)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but both solutions not working. First because of API 26 ir will show error `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : View!> findViewById(id: Int): T!
Please specify it explicitly.` For second Studio will suggest to remove explicit type argument but on building the same error of type mismatch will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

This question is several years old, but maybe my answer will help someone who comes across this question after making a simple error like I just did.

I came across a similar error (mine was `inferred type is View but ImageView was expected`) and while I was reading the answers here, I realized that I had two layouts generated by the primary/detail template in Android Studio. I had changed an element (`id/item_detail`) from `TextView` to `ImageView` in `res/layout/fragment_item_detail.xml`, but I only did it for the regular layout, and not for the layout in `res/layout-sw600dp/fragment_item_detail.xml`

Since the same id had different types in the two layouts, the binding couldn't cast the associated view to `ImageView`. Instead, it fell back to the common parent, which is `View`.

Changing both elements to `ImageView` (which is what I wanted anyway) fixed the error.

So, one thing you need to do to avoid this sort of error is to make sure that layout elements with the same id in the same-named layout files have the same class across all layout folders.