# findviewbuid as T in kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

My kotlin extension

```
fun <T> View.findViewByIdCast(id : Int): T {
return findViewById(id) as T}
```

my viewholder

```
var llImage: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewByIdCast(R.id.llImg)
```

I use this fun to get all of view item in my project,
but, in androidVersion 26
it show me "findviewbyid is not satisfied:inferred type T! is not a subtype of view"
 how could I Fix my extension fun in androidVersion 26?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API level 26, the [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) methods themselves (the Java methods in `AppCompatActivity`, `Fragment`, `View`) are generic - you no longer need to wrap them. You can see usage examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950543/4465208).

---

If for some reason you'd still want to wrap it (say you're making a library and you need to keep your public API or something), you'd need to:

- pass on the generic parameter
- which means you could now avoid the cast
- and finally, constraint `T` to satisfy the generic constraint on `findViewById` that its type parameter can only be a `View`

```
fun <T: View> View.findViewByIdCast(id: Int): T {
    return findViewById<T>(id)
}
```