# what is the purpose of angle brackets in Kotlin after a method that should require a parenthesis?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

On the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#kotlin) on RecyclerView,
is written

```
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recycler_view).apply {
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    setHasFixedSize(true)

    // use a linear layout manager
    layoutManager = viewManager
```

I cannot get the meaning of the angle bracket,
my intuition is that they are similar to the keyword `as`, is that correct?

```
recyclerView =  view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView

that I use in my Fragment( please notice the variable view
```

that I declarated into `onCreateView`

```
val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.bezinning_fragment, container, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

found it!
in this

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950401/not-able-to-findviewbyid-in-kotlin-getting-error-type-inference-failed) is clearly explained:

> You're on API level 26, where the return type of findViewById is now a
>   generic T instead of View and can therefore be inferred. You can see
>   the relevant changelog here.
>
> So you should be able to do this:
>
> val recycler_view = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view) Or
>   this:
>
> val recycler_view: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)