# Android Studio: A real rookie problem with my button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button

i don't know why but i get this error:

e: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\StorageManagementTheThird\app\src\main\java\com\example\storagemanagementthethird\AddItemActivity.kt: (15, 35): Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : View!> findViewById(p0: Int): T!

in this code:

```
class AddItemActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.add_item)


        val addItemSubmitButton = findViewById(R.id.addItemSubmitButton)

        addItemSubmitButton.setOnClickListener {

            val editTextItemName: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextItemName)

            //alles wat we aanpassen in storage en opslaan
            val database = getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            database.edit().apply {
                putString("savedItemName", editTextItemName.text.toString())
            }.apply()

        }
    }
}
```

please help me if you can :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Not enough information to infer parameter T" with Kotlin and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267041/not-enough-information-to-infer-parameter-t-with-kotlin-and-android)

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line

`val addItemSubmitButton = findViewById(R.id.addItemSubmitButton)`

like below

`val addItemSubmitButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.addItemSubmitButton)`

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` takes a type, so it can return the correct type of view - in this case you should probably use `findViewById<Button>` since that's what the view it meant to be, but it doesn't really matter since you can set a click listener on any type of `View`

If you actually specify the type on the `val` declaration, like `val addItemSubmitButton: Button` then the compiler can infer the type for the `findViewById` call, and you don't need the type in the diamond brackets (it'll be greyed out and you'll get a suggestion to delete it). That's why your `editTextItemName` lookup is fine - you're specifying the type for that one