# kotlin gives me an infer type error when using findViewById

Tags: android, kotlin

having a problem with my android studio.
I'm in a course so I need to fix.

**I use this line:**

```
val tvRslt: TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.tvRslt) }
```

**It gives this error:**
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in

The error disappear when I add the type like this: 
after findViewById like that:

```
val tvRslt: TextView by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvRslt) }
```

But I need to know how I can fix it to work like the first code here, becuase my code gives errors to my course mentor..

Thanks :)

Comment: Your second line (Casting to textView) is correct... what errors is your course mentor getting?

Comment: I think that the next link it will be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267041/not-enough-information-to-infer-parameter-t-with-kotlin-and-android

Answer (score 0):

Actually, updating kotlin version fixed the problem